# typescript: add items in an array if condition is true

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to populate an array `finalObject.members` using values from another arrays `allParticipants`. The second array (`allParticipants`) looks like this:

```
allParticipants = [
    { 
        uid:"mem1_100_00",
        member: "mem1",
        tontine: "100"
        total: 785
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem1_100_01",
        member: "mem1",
        tontine: "100"
        total: 800
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem1_200_00",
        member: "mem1",
        tontine: "200"
        total: 1000
    },
    {
        uid:"mem2_100_00",
        member: "mem2",
        tontine: "100"
        total: 200
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem2_200_00",
        member: "mem2",
        tontine: "200"
        total: 7850
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem2_200_01",
        member: "mem2",
        tontine: "200"
        total: 5000
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem2_200_02",
        member: "mem2",
        tontine: "200"
        total: 1600
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem3_100_00",
        member: "mem3",
        tontine: "100"
        total: 150
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem3_100_01",
        member: "mem3",
        tontine: "100"
        total: 0
    },
    { 
        uid:"mem3_200_00",
        member: "mem3",
        tontine: "200"
        total: 2500
    }

]
```

The first array (`finalObject.members`) is supposed to look like this after insertions:

```
finalObject.members = [
    { 
        uid: "mem1",
        tontines: {
            100:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_00",
                    total:785
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_01",
                    total:800
                },
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_200_00",
                    total:1000
                }
              ]
        }
    },
    { 
        uid: "mem2",
        tontines: {
            100: [
                {
                    uid: "mem2_100_00",
                    total: 200
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_00",
                    total: 7850
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_01",
                    total: 5000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_02",
                    total: 1600
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    { 
        uid: "mem3",
        tontines: {
            100: [
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_00",
                    total: 150                
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_01",
                    total: 0                
                }
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem3_200_00",
                    total: 2500        
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

So I wrote this code:

```
const sizMem    = finalObject.members.length;
const sizPartp  = allParticipants.length;

for(let idx1=0; idx1<sizPartp; idx1++){
    let partP = allParticipants[idx1]
    for(let idx2=0; idx2<sizMem; idx2++){
        let memP = finalObject.members[idx2];
        if(partP.member.localeCompare(memP.uid) == 0){
            finalObject.members[idx2].tontines[partP.tontine].push({
                uid:     partP.uid,
                total:   partP.total,
            })
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what I get:

```
finalObject.members = [
    { 
        uid: "mem1",
        tontines: {
            100:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_00",
                    total:785
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_01",
                    total:800
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_100_00",
                    total: 200
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_00",
                    total: 150                
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_01",
                    total: 0                
                }                    
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_200_00",
                    total:1000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_00",
                    total: 7850
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_01",
                    total: 5000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_02",
                    total: 1600
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_200_00",
                    total: 2500        
                }                    
              ]
        }
    },
    { 
        uid: "mem2",
        tontines: {
            100:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_00",
                    total:785
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_01",
                    total:800
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_100_00",
                    total: 200
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_00",
                    total: 150                
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_01",
                    total: 0                
                }                    
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_200_00",
                    total:1000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_00",
                    total: 7850
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_01",
                    total: 5000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_02",
                    total: 1600
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_200_00",
                    total: 2500        
                }                    
              ]
        }
    },
    { 
        uid: "mem3",
        tontines: {
            100:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_00",
                    total:785
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem1_100_01",
                    total:800
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_100_00",
                    total: 200
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_00",
                    total: 150                
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_100_01",
                    total: 0                
                }                    
            ],
            200:[
                {
                    uid: "mem1_200_00",
                    total:1000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_00",
                    total: 7850
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_01",
                    total: 5000
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem2_200_02",
                    total: 1600
                },
                {
                    uid: "mem3_200_00",
                    total: 2500        
                }                    
              ]
        }
    }
]
```

So it add all elements for each member instead of adding the new element only to the corresponding member. I ve checked the `if` conditions (but writing out result into console) and everything is okay on that part. The insertion is only executed when `member` property of `Participant` is the same as `uid` property of a `member`. Yet, it adds the new element everywhere!

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Could you please fix your code?  Missing commas, misspelled names, undefined variables...

Comment: @MichelBillaud Sorry but can you please point out those missing commas or mispelled names orundefined variables? `finalObject` is actually a bigger object but since I am just dealing with the `members` property, I just defined that part here.

Comment: Missing commas after all the "tontine" items. sizPartp undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where did I go wrong?

1. Your code is too complicated. Trying to do everything at one time with 2 embedded loops. Using indexes instead of (for...of) when indexes are not needed.
2. A more precise diagnostic: you have ONE push, where you have to add

   - new members
   - new tontines for a member
   - new participations for a tontine for a member

---

First indexing/grouping your data by member-id, then tontine-id, should help.

```
var participations = {}
for (let  p of allParticipations) {
    let member = p.member
    if ( ! (member in participations)) 
          participations[member] = { "member": member, "tontines" : {} }
    }  
    let tontine = p.tontine
    if ( ! (tontine in participations[member].tontines)) {
          participations[member].tontines[tontine] = [] 
    }
    participations[member].tontines[tontine].push( { "uid": p.uid, "total": p.total })
}
```

produces this:

```
{ 
  mem1: { member: 'mem1', tontines: { '100': [Array], '200': [Array] } },
  mem2: { member: 'mem2', tontines: { '100': [Array], '200': [Array] } },
  mem3: { member: 'mem3', tontines: { '100': [Array], '200': [Array] } } 
}
```

Indexing avoids you the searching loops. Then it's easy to build what you want from the participations variable.

---

EDIT : This intermediary data structure can be simplified to a doubly indexed dictionary of lists

```
var participations = {}
for (let p of allParticipations) {
    if ( ! (p.member in participations)) participations[p.member] = {}
    if ( ! (p.tontine in participations[p.member])) participations[p.member][p.tontine] = [] 
    participations[p.member][p.tontine].push({ "uid": p.uid, "total": p.total })
}
```

Result:

```
{ 
  mem1: { '100': [ [Object], [Object] ], '200': [ [Object] ] },
  mem2: { '100': [ [Object] ], '200': [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  mem3: { '100': [ [Object], [Object] ], '200': [ [Object] ] } 
}
```

---

EDIT 2: in a more functional-ish style, a general purpose multi-level indexing function sometimes helps. Like:

```
var x = indexBy(allParticipations,
                [ p => p.member, p => p.tontine ],    // keys
                p => ({ "uid"   : p.uid,               // items
                        "total" : p.total
                     })
           )
```

Source code:

```
function indexBy(data, extractors, finalizer) {
    let all_but_last = extractors.slice(0, extractors.length-1)
    let last = extractors[extractors.length-1]

    let result = {} 
    for (let item of data) {
        let node = result
        for (let extractor of all_but_last) {
            let key = extractor(item)
            if ( !(key in node)) node[key] = {}  // indexing all the way down
            node = node[key]
        }
        let key = last(item)
        if ( !(key in node)) node[key] = []   // last level is an array
        node[key].push(finalizer(item))
    }
    return result   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I really wanted it in the format I defined earlier. So I did the way you did, then transformed it into what I wanted, using `for(key in temMembers){  finalObject.members.push({ uid: key, tontines:tempMembers[key].tontines})}`  with `tempMembers` being the object you generated, and it worked great! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug. My small, dependency-free library [`blinq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blinq) is very well suited to these sorts of transformations.

```
const output = blinq(allParticipants)
  .groupBy(x => x.member)
  .select(g => ({
    uid: g.key,
    member: Object.fromEntries(
      g
      .groupBy(x => x.tontine)
      .select(gg => [
        gg.key,
        gg.select(x => ({
          uid: x.uid,
          total: x.total
        })).toArray()
      ])
      .toArray()
    )
  }))
  .toArray();
```

```js
const {
  blinq
} = window.blinq
const allParticipants = [{
    uid: "mem1_100_00",
    member: "mem1",
    tontine: "100",
    total: 785
  },
  {
    uid: "mem1_100_01",
    member: "mem1",
    tontine: "100",
    total: 800
  },
  {
    uid: "mem1_200_00",
    member: "mem1",
    tontine: "200",
    total: 1000
  },
  {
    uid: "mem2_100_00",
    member: "mem2",
    tontine: "100",
    total: 200
  },
  {
    uid: "mem2_200_00",
    member: "mem2",
    tontine: "200",
    total: 7850
  },
  {
    uid: "mem2_200_01",
    member: "mem2",
    tontine: "200",
    total: 5000
  },
  {
    uid: "mem2_200_02",
    member: "mem2",
    tontine: "200",
    total: 1600
  },
  {
    uid: "mem3_100_00",
    member: "mem3",
    tontine: "100",
    total: 150
  },
  {
    uid: "mem3_100_01",
    member: "mem3",
    tontine: "100",
    total: 0
  },
  {
    uid: "mem3_200_00",
    member: "mem3",
    tontine: "200",
    total: 2500
  }
];
const output = blinq(allParticipants)
  .groupBy(x => x.member)
  .select(g => ({
    uid: g.key,
    member: Object.fromEntries(
      g
      .groupBy(x => x.tontine)
      .select(gg => [
        gg.key,
        gg.select(x => ({
          uid: x.uid,
          total: x.total
        })).toArray()
      ])
      .toArray()
    )
  }))
  .toArray();
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blinq"></script>
```

Comment: Oops! I just saw your answer. I m sure it would also work great but I used the other answer to get to what I wannted. But I will definitely try yours, it looks kind of pro!

Comment: functional style is great